# Ace editor "Virtual Paths"

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

There is a lot of Javascript/Node culture I'm missing. So what are the virtual paths (my word) called in ace? These are not actual folders but created in the 'ace.js' file (for example, '/ace/mode/javascript'). What's the genesis of this approach to pathing? How do you enumerate or "see" the complete virtual directory structure for ace? I don't think the docs show this.

Thanks for any insight experts!

Answer (score 0):

After looking for clues on the ace git, I think this is accomplished by RequireJS. With RequireJS and webpack (and others I'm sure) you can build/compile modules to one file (ace.js in this case). The original folder structure is virtualized (my word) and files/modules can be accessed with paths as if they are in folders. Anyone know what javascript library originated this idea?